# Chrome extension manifest v3 with React

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking to add create a chrome extension with manifest v3 to use the scripting permission. I've created a React ui using v2 where I could copy over the dodgy SHA key from the Chrome error and make it allow it to run in my browser. Now in v3 the content_security_policy has changed to an object and with this version I can't get Chrome to allow my extension to show up. Have you got any idea how to get the chrome extension to play ball with my react app?

Getting an error:

```
Failed to load extension
File
\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\peterpoliwoda\Develop\git\react-plugin-typescript\build
Error
'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value "'sha256-m1InakbNccQ3GMWQxjDkpe3xtz7EYSSUcfxN6JYBtDk='" in directive 'script-src'.
Could not load manifest.
```

Comment: Not knowing how you use react and build it, I will offer a general comment as it relates to [CRA](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app): the build will inject an inline script. I suspect this is what the sha is referring to. You will need to replace this with a `<script/>` tag to avoid the need to configure CSP (automating this step would be nice but probably requires effort). Also see: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#content-security-policy part about what is allowed in CSP for extension pages.

Comment: Yes I am using the most standard, default Create React App build into the /build/ folder using react-scripts.

Comment: OK; go to build/index.html, look for the inlined script immediately after root. If you put that script in a js file and load it from there, does it solve the CSP issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Neea for helping with this. The problem is indeed with the inline script that React places in the `index.html` file at build stage. The fix is to place it inside of a separate script file. Sounds a little counter intuitive tbh but it works!

In index.html I needed to replace this:

```
<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>

<script>!function(e){function t(t){for(var n,i,a=t[0], 
...
</script>

<script src="/static/js/2.828ba7e0.chunk.js"></script>
...
```

with a simple script file, placed for example in the `static/js/inline.js` file together with the rest of the dynamically generated chunks:

```
<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="/static/js/inline.js"></script>

<script src="/static/js/2.828ba7e0.chunk.js"></script>
...
```

That's it! I will need to write a post-build script that will do this automatically now because doing it every time seems like a bit of a hassle.

**EDIT:**
You can use the `INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK` option in **Create React App** to remove the inline script directly. This fixes everything automagically! Run your build script with an environment variable:

```
export INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false; yarn build
```

That was the main problem. The error was actually related to the fact that I left the CSR value inside of the `manifest.yml` file:

```
...
"content_security_policy": {
  "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-m1InakbNccQ3GMWQxjDkpe3xtz7EYSSUcfxN6JYBtDk='; object-src 'self'"
  },
},
...
```